# When close set is not a compact set in Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, banach-spaces

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$ be any set and  the closure of $A,$ that is, $\bar{A}$ is not compact in $\mathbb R.$ Then $\bar{A}$ must be unbounded in $\mathbb R.$

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space  with the norm $\|\cdot \|_{X}$, and $K$ be any subset of $X$ with the property that $\bar{K}$ is not compact in $X.$

> My Question: What can we say about $\bar{K}$? Can we say there is a sequence $\{x_{n}\} \subset K $  and $\epsilon >0$ such that $\|x_n-x_{n'}\|_{X}\geq \epsilon$ for $n\neq n'$?

Comment: All we can say is that $\bar{K}$ is not [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space). This is not equivalent to bounded, it is a stronger condition.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\overline{K}$ is complete, since it is a closed subset of a complete space.  A metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded, so $\overline{K}$ is not totally bounded.  This means that for some $\epsilon>0$, for any finite subset $S\subseteq K$ there exists $x\in \overline{K}$ which is distance $>\epsilon$ from every point of $S$.  We can then use this to construct a sequence $(y_n)$ of points in $\overline{K}$ by induction, where at each step we choose $y_n$ such that $\|y_n-y_m\|>\epsilon$ for all $m<n$.  Now just choose $x_n\in K$ within $\epsilon/3$ of $y_n$ for each $n$, and the sequence $(x_n)$ satisfies $\|x_n-x_m\|>\epsilon/3$ for any distinct $m$ and $n$.